# Is Windows ping different than C# PingReply

Tags: c#, ping

I have an application that informs user when his internet connection has unacceptable delay (it's a voip application). I use following code to check the delay:

```
IPAddress address = GetIpFromHost(this._testAddress);
if (address != null)
{
this.SlowConnection = new SlowConnectionProblem(4, 100);

//set the ping options, TTL 128
PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions(128, true);

//create a new ping instance
Ping ping = new Ping();

//32 byte buffer (create empty)
byte[] buffer = new byte[32];

while (!_slowConnectionChecker.CancellationPending)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(this._checkInterval);
    try
    {
        //send the ping 4 times to the host and record the returned data.
        //The Send() method expects 4 items:
        //1) The IPAddress we are pinging
        //2) The timeout value
        //3) A buffer (our byte array)
        //4) PingOptions
        PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(address, 1000, buffer, pingOptions);

        //make sure we dont have a null reply
        if (!(pingReply == null))
        {
            if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                int time = Convert.ToInt32(pingReply.RoundtripTime);
                this.SlowConnection.addNewPingTime(time);
                if (this.SlowConnection.HasProblem)
                {
                    addConnectionProblem(this.SlowConnection);
                }
                else
                {
                    removeConnectionProblem(this.SlowConnection);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (PingException ex)
    {
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
    }
}
}
```

Generally the class containing above method calculates an average ping. Most of the time it works ok but few times I had a strange situation when in my application I had a warning displayed of high ping to google.pl - approx 128 ms and at the same time windows ping shows me approx 24 ms.

I checked the code carefully and it doesn't seem there is a mistake there.

Comment: My suggestion would be to capture both types of ICMP packages with Wireshark and compare them.

Answer (score 2):

To answer in short, YES they are the same mechanism.

**`PingReply` on MSDN**

> The Ping class attempts to send an Internet Control Message Protocol
>   (**ICMP**) echo request to a remote computer and receive information back
>   from the computer via an ICMP echo reply message. The Ping class uses
>   instances of the PingReply class to return information about the
>   operation, such as its status and the time taken to send the request
>   and receive the reply.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.pingreply%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

**`ping` command in windows**

> Verifies *IP-level* connectivity to another TCP/IP computer by sending
>   Internet Control Message Protocol (**ICMP**) Echo Request messages. The
>   receipt of corresponding Echo Reply messages are displayed, along with
>   round-trip times. Ping is the primary TCP/IP command used to
>   troubleshoot connectivity, reachability, and name resolution. Used
>   without parameters, ping displays help.
>
> http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ping.mspx?mfr=true

Note, IP level connectivity. Are you using TCP or UDP? These sit over IP and may cause you behaviour to differ.

---

> at the same time

Two ICMP pings are unlikely happen at the same time. Results will often be different as the IP routing is not guarenteed to be the same for each attempt. Have you considered pinging your call server rather than google? This will give you a better representation of you transfer quality. You probably want to measure *bandwidth*, not ping. A few hundred milliseconds here and there wont upset a call like it would a video game. You want to get the time-of-flight of a representative packet size, not the tiny ICMP packet.

Depending on your transport protocol, an ICMP ping may not give you the best representation of your call quality. You should consider a custom ping implementation that simulates you application as best as you can.

Comment: I am pinging google because ultimately my server may be down and google is up most of the time. This util is specifically for testing internet connection. Also we test the delay because when we install our app in some company they must provide minimum bandwith specified by us. Delay on the other hand may be bad even on high bandwith connection.

Comment: Generally among less then hundred companies having our application, in one company through all day today - windows ping show good result, app - above 100 ms. Thanks for pointing out TCP / UDP possible difference. I haven't found how to force one protocol thou.